# why the extra is "using where;using index" instead of "using index"

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

why the extra is "using where;using index" instead of "using index".

```
       CREATE TABLE `pre_count` (                
         `count_id` varchar(38) NOT NULL,        
         `cam_id` varchar(38) NOT NULL,       
         `count_time` datetime NOT NULL,         
         PRIMARY KEY (`cam_id`,`count_time`)  
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

explain `select count_time from pre_count where cam_id = '56849645645645646'`

the result：

```
1   SIMPLE  pre_count   ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 116 const   1   Using where; Using index
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?  I see do not see "Using where" when I try the most recent version of MySQL (8.0.16).

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that conditions in your WHERE clause are going to be used to restrict the rows returned by the query. If you *don't* have "Using where" in your EXPLAIN extra, then the query will not restrict rows.

That's the meaning according to the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information

> A WHERE clause is used to restrict which rows to match against the next table or send to the client. Unless you specifically intend to fetch or examine all rows from the table, you may have something wrong in your query if the Extra value is not Using where and the table join type is *ALL* or *index*.

I could swear that I've seen cases where "Using where" was missing from my EXPLAIN report, even though the query did use an index and restricted the rows to return.

I'm forced to conclude that "Using where" is not reported reliably for all types of row restrictions.

Other people have noticed that the meaning of "Using where" is confusing or inconsistent: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30733

Comment: I would call this inadequate docs. `Using where` -- as I have always understood it -- means conditions in the where clause must be evaluated against *found* rows... that is, the storage engine layer is expected to potentially return too many rows, so they are to be further filtered at the MySQL layer -- so any query that's cleanly resolved with an index lookup would not have this.  I would not expect to see it appear for the query shown.  The only thing I can think of is that the optimizer is distracted by the second column in the PK not being included in `WHERE`.

Comment: Indeed, even reading the [source code for explain](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/opt_explain.cc#L994) doesn't really shed any light on it. The code logic appears to be, "if it's an explain for a table (i.e. not a subquery), and it's not a 'range checked for each record' and there's a condition for row restriction, then report 'Using where'." But that doesn't cover situations where we know 'Using where' does not appear.

Comment: I find that `Using where` in `EXPLAIN` is useless noise.